# session expire on time in php

Tags: php, session

I am new to Php.I am developing a website and I have used session for login and logout code.I am just trying to know that how to expire my session after specific time.eg say 20 minutes of idle use.
My login code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("config.php");

session_start();

// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 1200;

// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
    if($session_life > $inactive) {
        session_destroy(); header("Location: logout.php"); 
    }
}

$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']); 
    $mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);
    $sql="SELECT rid FROM register WHERE rname='$myusername' and rpass='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    @$active=$row['active'];
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1) {
        $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
        window.location.assign('Home.php')</script>";
    }
    else {
        $error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>

<title>Login Page</title>


</head>
<body>    
<div style="margin:30px">    
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName  :</label><input type="text" name="username" required="required" class="box"/><br /><br />
<label>Password  :</label><input type="password" name="password" required="required" class="box" /><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Submit "/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset"/><br />
<br />
Not a member yet..? &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a href="register.php">Register</a></li>

</form>
<div style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo @$error; ?></div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and logout code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
?>
```

This code runs fine but user can't login.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You don't have any actual security.

Comment: In short: Security is _hard_.  Do not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: yep I am using salt and hashing just not given here.

Comment: PHP cannot logout someone out if you refer to the client side. It can only destroy the session on server side. What happens after that is up to your implementation. Oh, and you should expire / delete the cookie.

Comment: So my code should send me to logout page after idle 20 minutes .

Comment: Try to use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never setting `$_SESSION['start']`. This line

```
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
```

should probably be

```
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
```

shouldn't it?

Comment: With help of your code I can login now but still no logout after idle time.Any help for that part.

Comment: Is the `// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set`-block included in every script or is it just on the login page?

Comment: My bad ... I just forgot to refresh the page.Its working fine.But it would have been better if the code would have executed after idle time its logging out anyway idle or not.Anything to say ?